# make a div fade out depending on result from maths in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

All i want to do is make a div fade out based on the result of a count script i have written. Everything works fine, however the only thing that doesnt work fine is the div fading out when the value is returned into a div called counter. Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/fBqRK/ and the javascript code is below:

jquery -

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function(){

   // Count all of the checked boxes and then output the result
   var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
   var fadespeed = 500;
   $('#counter').text(count).fadeIn(fadespeed);

   // Now, depending on the results, display some stuff
    var message = $('#message');
    if(count >= 8){
        message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You have done really well');
    } else if (count >= 4) {
        message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You are sort of okay');
    } else {
        message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You are terrible, sorry.')   
    }
});

if($('#counter').text() == 2){
    $('#buttons').fadeOut(500);
}
```

HTML -

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes"/>


<div id="trigger">Click to count 'em</div>
<div id="counter"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="buttons">Buttons</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `if statement` will be run when the page loads, well when the JS file is open and exucuted. You'll want to move the if block into the click event ie:

```
 $('#trigger').on('click', function(){

      // Count all of the checked boxes and then output the result
      var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
      var fadespeed = 500;
      $('#counter').text(count).fadeIn(fadespeed);

      // Now, depending on the results, display some stuff
       var message = $('#message');
       if(count >= 8){
         message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You have done really well');
     } else if (count >= 4) {
         message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You are sort of okay');
     } else {
         message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You are terrible, sorry.')   
     }

      if($('#counter').text() == 2){
          $('#buttons').fadeOut(500);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `if` statement inside the click handler and use `count` instead of `$('#counter').text()`.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBqRK/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function(){

   // Count all of the checked boxes and then output the result
   var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
   var fadespeed = 500;
   $('#counter').text(count).fadeIn(fadespeed);

   // Now, depending on the results, display some stuff
    var message = $('#message');
    if(count >= 8){
        message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You have done really well');
    } else if (count >= 4) {
        message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You are sort of okay');
    } else {
        message.fadeIn(fadespeed).text('You are terrible, sorry.')   
    }

    if(count == 2){
        $('#buttons').fadeOut(500);
    }

});
```

Tried it in the fiddle.. works like a charm..